# Illegal Characters Check -- Function works just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following a solution using by a member, we found a bug to it. Am trying to check for illegal characters when submit button of the input box and or text area is clicked.

This was the solution

```
$('.someclass').blur(function () {if (/[%&<>\[\]{}]/.test(this.value) === true) {
    alert('These characters & < > [ ] { } % are not allowed.  Please remove them and try again.');
}});
```

This worked but on the second click it did not check. 1st submit -- alert message, 2nd submit - no alert and saved.

Can any one improve on this ?

Also I have tried it a different way using onclick but it works only on the first text area but not on the subsequent text area or input box. Please take a look at the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AR323/5/)?

Another function has the same problem as above.

```
function spCheck () {
var str = $("textarea, input[type='text']").val();
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(str) == false) {
alert('You have entered illegal characterss. Please remove them and try again.');
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated..Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `blur` event? Your jsfiddle behaves correctly (as - checking the value every time).

Comment: Hi! That was the solution given to me. In my fiddle, if you enter & just in the second text area or the input boxes, it does not work.

Comment: Ok - your fiddle was incorrect, as you haven't defined the spCheck function - here's the fixed one: http://jsfiddle.net/AR323/6/. Still, the original fiddle works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but it still does not work. Tried both in Chrome and Opera. I entered just & in the just in the second textarea.

Comment: Looking back at the code I can see now why it was working for me. Here's again, the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/AR323/7/. Now the values for each of the buttons are being taken correctly. I'm still suspecting the `blur` to be causing the problems in your original query, but I won't be able to provide answer without more code.

Comment: Looks like it is working now..thanks ever so much...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41701/discussion-between-19eggs-and-eithed)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a smarter solution would be using the `keyup` event so that you can check the entered characters as the user types them. While performing this check, you can also disable the form's submission if an error has encountered:

```
$( "input" ).on( "keyup", function() {
  var value = $( this ).val();
  var invalidChars = [ '<', '>', '{', '}', '‰' ];
  if( $.inArray( value, invalidChars ) ) {
    $( "form" ).data( "invalid", true );
  }
  // message
});

$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( e ) {
  var $form = $( this);
  if( $form.data( "invalid" ) ) {
     e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Just sync the two routines and you're set.

Comment: Hi! Gabriele, Thanks but we need to make sure it works for copy paste as well.

Comment: Use also the `paste` event then. ;-)